# Custom formatting date when writing to sheet

Tags: excel, vba, date-formatting

I'm having a problem getting a date formatted correctly when copying to a worksheet on a blank/un-formatted line.

I am using a macro to copy values from one sheet to another and I want one column to contain the current date that the script was run on.

Here is what I have:

```
records_list.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & records_row_number) = 
Format(Date, "ddmmmyy")
```

This is working correctly in that it is putting a date value in to the target sheet (records_list). However, the formatting is coming in as "d-mmm-yy" which means it contains the dashes and drops the leading zero in the days.

I want the date in the format 09Oct18 but it is displaying as 9-Oct-18

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it's doing this or how to prevent it. I've tried lots of suggestions for date formatting I've seen on other sites but nothing is working. If I go into the cell formatting and force it to "ddmmmyy" it displays correctly, however, I want to avoid pre-formatting thousands of rows in the sheet so that it opens/saves faster.

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses the range's numberformat when choosing how to display a date, not the format it was written to the range in. To change the numberformat of the range, you can do something like:

```
With records_list.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & records_row_number)
    .Value = Date
    .NumberFormat = "ddmmmyy"
End With
```

Comment: @MadChef If the answer worked for you, you can mark it as a solution by clicking the green tick mark under the vote arrows.

Answer (score -1):

This needs to be done in two step. First enter Value and then set Number Format:

```
records_list.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & records_row_number).Value = Date
records_list.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & records_row_number).NumberFormat = "ddmmmyy"
```

or even better using With:

```
With records_list.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & records_row_number)
    .Value = Date
    .NumberFormat = "ddmmmyy"
End With
```